# Angular Bootstrap Carousel pauses when hovering over even with no-pause set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstraps carousel in my project. I have set up my controller like this:

```
.controller('HomeController', function () {
    var self = this;

    self.interval = 2000;
    self.designer = [{
        image: '/assets/images/carousel/designer/slide-1.jpg'
    }, {
        image: '/assets/images/carousel/designer/slide-2.jpg'
    }, {
        image: '/assets/images/carousel/designer/slide-3.jpg'
    }, {
        image: '/assets/images/carousel/designer/slide-4.jpg'
    }, {
        image: '/assets/images/carousel/designer/slide-5.jpg'
    }, {
        image: '/assets/images/carousel/designer/slide-6.jpg'
    }];
});
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<div carousel interval="controller.interval" no-pause controls="false">
    <div slide ng-repeat="slide in controller.designer" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{ slide.image }}" style="margin:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

For this particular carousel I don't want to have the controls.
There is no attribute to remove controls by default (I checked the JS file), so at first I just added some CSS to handle this for me:

```
.no-controls .carousel-indicators, 
.no-controls .carousel-control {
    display: none; 
}
```

Which seemed to work fine, but there is an issue when hovering over the controls. It pauses the carousel which I do not want. So I decided to create a directive that **requires** the carousel directive like this:

```
.directive('controls', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'carousel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            // Assign our variables
            var showControls = attr.controls ? false : true;

            // If we do not want to show the controls
            if (!showControls) {

                // Get the element children
                var children = element.children();

                // Loop through our element children
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

                    // Get our current child
                    var child = angular.element(children[i]);

                    // If we our class exists
                    if (child.hasClass('carousel-indicators') || child.hasClass('carousel-control')) {

                        // Remove the child
                        child.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is checks to see if we have set our directive up like this: **controls="false"** and if we have then it loops through the carousels children removing any control that is found.

The problem is that when I hover over the carousel it still pauses. Does anyone know how to stop it pausing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. I did not need a directive.
Firstly, I changed my view to this:

```
<div carousel interval="controller.interval">
    <div slide ng-repeat="slide in controller.designer" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{ slide.image }}" style="margin:auto;">
    </div>
</div>

<script id="template/carousel/carousel.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="carousel carousel-no-controls">
        <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and then I created some CSS like this:

```
.carousel-no-controls {
    cursor: default; 
}
```

and that was it. Started working fine.

Comment: Or you can change the **no-pause** attribute to **no-pause="true"** :/